# Proof environment with scshape

Tags: environments, theorems

I want

```
\newtheorem*{prf}{\normalfont\scshape Proof}
```

but with an automatic \qedsymbol at the end (QED).

Comment: You want the proof to end with the acronym QED? (or maybe EOΔ ?)

Comment: @Bernard sorry it took so long to get back to you, I want the acronym QED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do this with `ntheorem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

 \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\upshape\bfseries}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}


\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theoremseparator{:}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\color{Gainsboro}\blacksquare}}
\newtheorem{prf}{Proof}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{th-a}
This theorem is awesome!
\end{thm}

\begin{prf}
One-lined proof: Blahblah Blahblah Blahblah.
\end{prf}

\begin{prf}[Variant]
This is a very important proof.
\begin{align*}
    a & = b\\ c & = d.
\end{align*}
\end{prf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wrote ````\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theoremseperator{:}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{QED}
\newtheorem{prf}{Proof}
````` and I got ````! Package ntheorem Error: Theorem style plain already defined. ! LaTeX Error: Environment equation* undefined. ! Undefined control sequence.````

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with the usual `proof` environment of `amsthm`. It has an optional argument to set the name of the proof, so you can also pass `\normalfont\scshape` to this argument to set the font.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem*{thm}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{prf}[1][Proof]{%
    \begin{proof}[\normalfont\scshape #1]%
}{%
    \end{proof}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
A theorem.
\end{thm}
\begin{prf}
The proof.
\end{prf}
\end{document}
```

[image]